# How I use this jquery function correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown and its populating with dynamic data. Here I have used a function to call ajax and get the dynamic data.

This is how I create this function:

```
function Banks($selecter, selected) {

 // my stuff ----

}
```

I am using it like this when the document ready:

```
Banks($('#DropDownEdit'));
```

HTML look like this:

```
<select id="DropDownEdit" name="bank_one" data-id="4"></select>
```

Now I need to get `data-id` value to the function when document is ready.

I tried it something like this:

```
$(document).on('change', '#DropDownEdit', function(){
  var ID     = $(this).data('id');
  Banks($('#DropDownEdit'), ID);

});
```

But It doesn't work for me. Can anybody tell me how I do this rightly?

Comment: What exactly does not work? Please put more details into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ID = $('#DropDownEdit').data('id');
})
```

Comment: $() is the same as $(document).ready in JQuery, try to optimise the Jquery if giving an answer e.g `$(function(){
    var ID = $('#DropDownEdit').data('id');
})`

Comment: There is some good documentation about it here: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: @hjardine I do know that but it also says some thing more. which is this "Experienced developers sometimes use the shorthand $() for $( document ).ready(). If you are writing code that people who aren't experienced with jQuery may see, it's best to use the long form."

Comment: And I think the OP is not well acquainted with jQuery, so its best for him to go through basics and slowly start using shorthand.

Comment: I completely agree, but you should also inform them about the other options so they can develop and continue to learn, I would have put, after the answer "you can also use $() instead of $(document).ready once you develop your understanding of JQuery as you can see here [LINK TO SITE]" as I believe Stack is for learning as much as it is for developing answers to questions :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `HTML` markup seems to be all wrong. An empty `select` tag is not a valid markup and `onchage` never triggers for an empty `select`. The `select` tag must have at least one `option` inside.

```
<select id="DropDownEdit" name="bank_one" data-id="4">
    <option value="one">1</option>
    <option value="two">2</option>
    <option value="three">3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/y6bqschk/)

I have updated the event delegation assignment as following and it works

```
function Banks($selecter, selected) {
  //alert(selected);
  $selecter.append('<option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option>')
    // my stuff ----

}

$(function () {
  Banks($('#DropDownEdit'), $('#DropDownEdit').data('id'));
  $('#DropDownEdit').on('change', function () {
    var ID = $(this).data('id');
    alert(ID);
    Banks($('#DropDownEdit'), ID);
  });
});
```

Hope it works for you

Answer (score 0):

> You need to get data-id value to the function when document is ready.

try to use $(document).ready();

`$(document).**ready**(function(){
      var ID     = $('#DropDownEdit').data('id');
      Banks($('#DropDownEdit'), ID);
    });`

hope this help.

Comment: Oh , Sorry for dupplicate answer.